# PHP Notice: Undefined offset in class-gd-system-plugin-config.php

Tags: php, undefined

I am getting this message:

> PHP Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in
>   /home/printet1/public_html/wp-content/mu-plugins/gd-system-plugin/class-gd-system-plugin-config.php on line 56

The relevant code is:

```
public function get_config( ) {
  if ( empty( $this->config ) ) {
   $defaults = $this->_get_config( '/web/conf/gd-wordpress.conf' );
   $resellers = $this->_get_config( '/web/conf/gd-resellers.conf' );
   $reseller = null;
   if ( defined( 'GD_RESELLER' ) && is_numeric( GD_RESELLER ) ) {
    $reseller = $resellers[GD_RESELLER];
   }
   if ( is_array( $reseller ) && !empty( $reseller ) ) {
    $this->config = array_merge( $defaults, $reseller );
   } else {
    $this->config = $defaults;
   }
  }
  return $this->config;
 }
```

With line 56 specifically being:

$reseller = $resellers[GD_RESELLER];

I'm relatively new to coding and would like any information/help on what I can do to fix this. I have read explanations on what is going wrong  but don't understand what to do in order to address this issue.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Is GD_RESELLER a constant? if so is it meant to be in quotes when checking if it is defined? or vise versa, if it's not a constant then it needs to be in quotes on is_numeric() and $resellers[GD_RESELLER]

Comment: What does `$resellers` contains? `@ line 55: var_dump($resellers);`

Comment: It looks like that `GD_SELLER` constant value is `1` and there is only `1` or less items in `$resellers` array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that $resellers array doesn't hold the value you are looking for.
one way to debug this, is to add

```
var_dump(GD_RESELLER);
var_dump($resellers);
```

to line 55, just before this line:

```
$reseller = $resellers[GD_RESELLER];
```

to get an idea of what's going on.

if 'GD_RESELLER' is a number, make sure that $resellers array has a value in that position. i.e:

if $reseller array looks like this:

```
array(3) { [0]=> string(5) "first" [1]=> string(6) "second" [2]=> string(5) "third" } string(5)
```

and GD_RESELLER constant equels '2', then asking for

```
$resellers[GD_RESELLER]
```

will return `'third'`

remember that arrays in PHP use zero-based index,

so the first child of that array is in position **'0'** and not **'1'**, etc.

See PHP's **[Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/)** about **[Arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)**

Answer (score 0):

Another simple solution, just edit bellow code in gd-config.php file.

> define( 'GD_RESELLER', false);